# What are the differences of the Open Connectivity Foundation membership levels?

Tags: ocf

Can someone explain to me the differences between [Diamond, Platinum and Gold membership](https://openconnectivity.org/about/membership-list) at the OCF?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Honestly, not much really - only the price difference to become a member, better advertising and more power in the organization.

[The corresponding form to become a member](https://openconnectivity.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/OCF-Diamond-Platinum-Gold-Membership-Agreement-Amended06062016.pdf) is here. They all must follow the bylaws shown [here](https://openconnectivity.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Sixth-Amended-Bylaws-Open-Connectivity-Foundation_03142016.pdf).

> SECTION 14.1 DIAMOND MEMBERS
>
> 1. The Corporation shall have Diamond Members. Any applicant qualified under Section
>      12.2 wishing to become a Diamond Member after the Organizational Meeting must be approved via 3/4 vote of all current Directors
>      appointed by Diamond Members with such vote occurring via electronic
>      means. Following an affirmative vote of the Diamond Members, an
>      applicant for Diamond Membership shall be admitted to membership upon
>      execution of a Diamond membership agreement.
> 2. Diamond Members who remain in good standing shall be: a. Perpetually eligible to appoint a representative to the Board of
>      Directors of the Corporation in accordance with these Bylaws; b.
>      Eligible to have a representative appointed or elected as an officer
>      of the Corporation; c. Eligible to participate in the Work Groups of
>      the Corporation and have a representative chair the same; and d.
>      Subject to procedures and requirements as may be adopted by the
>      Corporation, eligible to seek certification of the Member’s products
>      and/or services and use the Corporation’s trademarks in connection
>      with the Member’s certified products or services.
> 3. Diamond Members may be downgraded to Platinum Members (or at their option Gold Members) upon unanimous vote of all Directors appointed by
>      Diamond Members, less one (1), when such Directors determine, after
>      affording the Diamond Member in question the right to be heard on the
>      issue, that the Diamond Member has failed to actively contribute to
>      the work of the Corporation.
>
> SECTION 14.2 PLATINUM MEMBERS
>
> 1. The Corporation shall have Platinum Members. Any applicant qualified under Section
>      12.2 wishing to become a Platinum Member shall be admitted to membership upon its execution of the appropriate Membership Agreement.
> 2. Platinum Members who remain in good standing shall be:
>
>    - Eligible to have a representative elected to the Board of Directors in
>        accordance with these Bylaws;
>    - Eligible to have a representative
>        appointed or elected as an officer of the Corporation;  PAGE - 21
>        BYLAWS OF OPEN CONNECTIVITY FOUNDATION, INC.
>        PDX\127875\200109\TFH\17626740.1
>    - Eligible to participate in the
>        Work Groups of the Corporation and have a representative chair the
>        same; and
>    - Subject to procedures and requirements as may be adopted
>        by the Corporation, eligible to seek certification of the Member’s
>        products and/or services and use the Corporation’s trademarks in
>        connection with the Member’s certified products or services. SECTION
>
> 14.3 GOLD MEMBERS
>
> 1. The Corporation shall have Gold Members. Any applicant qualified under Section 12.2 shall be admitted to membership upon its execution
>      of the appropriate Membership Agreement.
> 2. Gold Members who remain in good standing shall be: a. Eligible to participate in the Work Groups of the Corporation in a non-voting
>      capacity; and b. Subject to procedures and requirements as may be
>      adopted by the Corporation, eligible to seek certification of the
>      Member’s products and/or services and use the Corporation’s trademarks
>      in connection with the Member’s certified products or services.
> 3. The Corporation may also have Nonprofit/Educational Gold Members. Any entity who qualifies as a nonprofit or educational entity under
>      the laws and regulations of its domicile jurisdiction may apply for
>      Membership as a Nonprofit/Educational Gold Member. The Board of
>      Directors shall review any and all applications for such level of
>      Membership and may, in their sole discretion, accept such application
>      upon a determination that the applicant meets the requirements for
>      this membership subset. a. Noprofit/Educational Members who remain in
>      good standing shall be entitled to all Membership benefits of Gold
>      Members; provided, however, that Nonprofit/Educational Membership
>      benefits (including but not limited to rights under the IPR Policy and
>      the right to receive or review Confidential Information) shall not
>      extend beyond employees of the nonprofit or educational entity. For
>      avoidance of doubt, it is expressly understood that membership rights
>      and benefits do not extend to members or participants in nonprofit
>      entities, their employees or contractors, or to governmental entities
>      other than the educational entity applicant.

It's a lot to process, but pretty much any member must comply with their guideline for devices, but as you go up you get more power to influence what the guidelines of the OCF are.

Other than that, between Gold and Platinum, they seem to bump up how much space you get on the membership list.